# Selecting columns from a table in memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've declared a table in memory.

```
DECLARE @T1 table(
    a    int,
    b    varchar(300),
    c    char(60)
)
```

Now I need to use values from `@T1` and existing table `IMMASTER`.

```
SELECT @T1.*, IMMASTER.d 
FROM @T1 JOIN IMMASTER 
ON @T1.a = IMMASTER.a
```

The table exists in memory, but I apparently cannot reference its columns on the fly with `@T1`.[column] - I get:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@T1".`

How do I properly retrieve columns from `@T1` in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to select * from the table variable, you should also alias your table as its better form:

```
SELECT T1.*, IMM.d 
FROM @T1 as T1 
JOIN IMMASTER  as IMM
ON T1.a = IMM.a
```

Comment: correct solution @sirius_pain (same as mine) but i'd encourage you to read the link i posted to. It's important.

Comment: It's more than just better form, `@T1.*` will throw an error.  What's odd is that it will throw a `incorrect syntax near *` error which isn't the one listed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a table variable that's in `tempdb`, which may be in the memory buffer but don't think that it's not using `tempdb`. [So the blanket statement that you created a table in memory is inaccurate](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/12/15/sql-server-difference-temptable-and-table-variable-temptable-in-memory-a-myth/).

Use a table alias to fix the error.

```
SELECT t.*, IMMASTER.d 
FROM @T1 as t JOIN IMMASTER 
ON t.a = IMMASTER.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the table and run any other queries against the table at the same time.

If you highlight just the select and not the declare, you will get the error you are getting.

Also, if you use `GO` anywhere between the declaration and your query, you will also get that error.

If you have to separate the query from the declare, use a `#` temp table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(a    int,
 b    varchar(300),
 c    char(60))
```

Note that `@T1` doesn't have any data in it, and in your query you will need an alias - `@T1.*` will throw an error.